# Adding dynamic <option> to select doesn't show unless I switch the field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to be able to add Group Members dynamically and I simply used + button for that. The problem is - it adds the input value of the prompt, but I can't see it unless I switch fields and type something else. 
Here is the YouTube link for better understanding:
https://youtu.be/sA0WB2Le3Fg

```
<button id="add" type="button" onClick={(e)=>this.addMember(e)}>+</button>
```

The state :

```
 members: [
        {member:"Berin"},
        {member:"Cristian"},
        {member:"Raddy"},
        {member:"Ventsislav"},
      ]
```

The function :

```
  addMember = (e) => {
    let input = prompt("Enter the name");
    this.state.members.push({member:input});
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

The mapping function :

```
let members = this.state.members.map((member,index)=>{
          return <option value={member.member} key={index}>{member.member}</option>
        })
```

The select field :

```
<select id="groupMember" onChange={this.changeMember} name="member" required>
  <option defaultValue="" selected disabled>Select group member</option>
 {members}
</select>
```

Comment: Try using the `setState` method within `addMember` instead of modifying state directly.

Comment: Upvoted for providing a video showing the exact issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  addMember = (e) => {
    let input = prompt("Enter the name");
    let newMemberList = this.state.members;
    newMemberList.push(input);
    this.setState({ members: newMemberList });
    e.preventDefault();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Recommended approach in the later React versions looks like this:

```
addMember = (e) => {
    let input = prompt("Enter the name");
    this.setState(prevState => ({
        members: [...prevState.members, input]
    }))
    e.preventDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ! Already found the solution :

```
addMember = (e) => {
    let input = prompt("Enter the name");
    let members = this.state.members;
    members.push({member:input})
    e.preventDefault();
    this.setState({
      ...this.state,
      members
    })
```